# Using tensorflow object detection in another model

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I am trying to use Tensorflow (tf) object detection API models in another custom model I built. Specifically, I am trying to do:

- jointly train tf object detection models Y with another model X.
- in a parallel experiment, just train model X while obtaining tf object detection model Y predictions and incorporating it into X (in some way).

I have gone through the official tf object detection API [docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) and scoured the net trying to find good examples where tf object detection API was customized for cases beyond just object detection. I haven't found any. Any help or links would be appreciated.